# Pandas `apply` into multiple columns consuming lots of memory

Tags: pandas

I have a function that, given a value, returns a numpy array of size 100. I want to apply this to a series and create a dataframe from it with each column being a different position in the array returned by the function. This is easy enough with Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# placeholder for real function
def process(x):
    return np.random.rand(100)

s = pd.Series(range(2700000))
df = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(process(x)))
```

Unfortunately, this consumes A LOT of RAM. It consumes at least 16GB and starts swapping on my machine, and I have to eventually run this code on a machine with only half that much memory.

If I instead write `s.apply(lambda x: process(x))`, it does not consume nearly as much memory but this does not get the layout I want. Is there a way to do this without consuming massive amounts of RAM?

I am using Pandas 0.17.1 and Numpy 1.9.2.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2700000, 100))` or is this just some sample question about memory consumption?

Comment: The `process` function above is just a placeholder of the real function. The real function is not just `np.random.rand(100)`.

Comment: Well the layout difference is that there is a semantic difference between returning something that is just array-like such as np arrays or lists, to a Series where the index is used to form the columns, it's possible this is a performance bug or that when using `apply` it can't figure out how large the resultant df will be. What version numpy and pandas are you using?

Comment: Pandas is 0.17.1 and numpy is 1.9.2.

Comment: It maybe worth posting as a question on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues about this

Comment: I have gone ahead and done so: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12584. I would still very much appreciate a workaround, if anyone can find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found a solution to my problem. This seems to use much less memory, is pretty fast, and keeps the index like an `apply` does:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(map(process, s)), index=s.index)
```